# How to find text within page if it is in different variation?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have an element for example `<span class="ads_price" id="tdo_8">7 650 €</span>` and I need to find this element by price, but the problem is that I do not know in what form the price will be. I need to make my search for this substring in element reinforced so it does not have problems in any scenario. For example if I search for price of `7650` it will not find this element, but if I search for `7 650`(notice the space) then it will find it with no issues. For now I'm using search by xpath `//*[contains(text(),'{search_price}')]`. My question - is there any way I can improve this search for any price for ANY page I throw at it?

P.S. I'm using scrapy with no javascript rendered webpages.

Comment: Why don't you use either the class or id to search for the price?

Comment: look for the € instead of the number

Comment: @msenior_ I'm not making this only for one website. This needs to be usable on any site where I can copy the price and search it with xpath.

Comment: @grumpyp The € sign is not used on every site so it is not reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will work for you:

```
response.xpath("//*[contains(translate(text(),' ',''),'7650')]").getall()
```

This will return all the elements that contain `7650` - with or without space, with or without $, €, etc.

I have tested this with:

```
<span class="ads_price" id="tdo_8">7 650 €</span>
<span class="ads_price" id="tdo_8">7 650 </span>
<span class="ads_price" id="tdo_8">$ 7650</span>
<span class="ads_price" id="tdo_8">7650.30</span>
```